# Pymongo failing but won't give exception

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is the query in Pymongo

```
import mong #just my library for initializing
collection_1 = mong.init(collect="col_1")
collection_2 = mong.init(collect="col_2")

for name in collection_2.find({"field1":{"$exists":0}}):
    try:
            to_query = name['something']
            actual_id = collection_1.find_one({"something":to_query})['_id']
            crap_id = name['_id']
            collection_2.update({"_id":id},{"$set":{"new_name":actual_id}},upset=True)
    except:
            open('couldn_find_id.txt','a').write(name)
```

All this is doing is taking a field from one collection, finding the id of that field and updating the id of another collection. It works for about 1000-5000 iterations, but periodically fails with this and then I have to restart the script.

```
 > Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "my_query.py", line 6, in <module>
 for name in collection_2.find({"field1":{"$exists":0}}):
 File "/home/user/python_mods/pymongo/pymongo/cursor.py", line 814, in next
   if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
 File "/home/user/python_mods/pymongo/pymongo/cursor.py", line 776, in _refresh
   limit, self.__id))
 File "/home/user/python_mods/pymongo/pymongo/cursor.py", line 720, in __send_message
self.__uuid_subtype)
 File "/home/user/python_mods/pymongo/pymongo/helpers.py", line 98, in _unpack_response
cursor_id)
 pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cursor id '7578200897189065658' not valid at server
 ^C
 bye
```

Does anyone have any idea what this failure is, and how I can turn it into an exception to continue my script even at this failure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is described in [pymongo's FAQ](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#what-does-operationfailure-cursor-id-not-valid-at-server-mean):

> Cursors in MongoDB can timeout on the server if they’ve been open for
>   a long time without any operations being performed on them. This can
>   lead to an OperationFailure exception being raised when attempting to
>   iterate the cursor.

This is because of the `timeout` argument of [collection.find()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find):

> timeout (optional): if True (the default), any returned cursor is
>   closed by the server after 10 minutes of inactivity. If set to False,
>   the returned cursor will never time out on the server. Care should be
>   taken to ensure that cursors with timeout turned off are properly
>   closed.

Passing `timeout=False` to the `find` should fix the problem:

```
for name in collection_2.find({"field1":{"$exists":0}}, timeout=False):
```

But, be sure you are closing the cursor properly.

Also see:

- [mongodb cursor id not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298354/cursor-id-not-valid-error)