# Cursor id not valid at server even with no_cursor_timeout=True

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "from_mongo.py", line 27, in <module>
    for sale in pm.events.find({"type":"sale", "date":{"$gt":now-(_60delta+_2delta)}}, no_cursor_timeout=True, batch_size=100):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 968, in __next__
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 922, in _refresh
self.__id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 838, in __send_message
codec_options=self.__codec_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 110, in _unpack_response
cursor_id)
pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: cursor id '1025112076089406867' not valid at server
```

I have also experimented with bigger or lower batch size, and no no_cursor_timeout at all. I have even managed to get this error on a very small collection (200 documents with id and title). It seems to happen when the database is not responsive (heavy inserts). The setup is a cluster of 3 shards of 3 replica sets (9 mongodb instances), mongodb 3.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb cursor id not valid error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298354/mongodb-cursor-id-not-valid-error)

Comment: How are you creating MongoClient? Are you passing the address of one mongos, or multiple?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Error: getMore command failed: Cursor not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248108/mongodb-error-getmore-command-failed-cursor-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the line numbers in your traceback, it looks like you're using PyMongo 3, which was released last week. Are you using multiple mongos servers in a sharded clusters? If so, the error is probably a symptom of a critical new bug in PyMongo 3:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-898

It will be fixed in PyMongo 3.0.1, which we'll release within a week.

Comment: you are right, it actually WAS 3.0 with multiple mongos+sharding, but on my dev machine it was a different version (2.8).

Answer (score 0):

It just hit me that I thought I was using pymongo 3.0 which has a flag called `no_cursor_timeout=True`, when in fact I was using 2.8.