# Command getMore failed: End of file MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
    MongoCursor<BsonDocument> mongoCursor = 
      mongoCollection.Find(Query.And(some query))
       .SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout)
       .SetFields(idFieldName);

    int totalCount = 0;
    Queue<List<long>> idBatchQueue = new Queue<List<long>>();
    List<long> idBatch = new List<long>(batchSize);
    foreach (BsonDocument document in mongoCursor)
    {
        idBatch.Add(document[idFieldName].ToInt64());
        if (idBatch.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            idBatchQueue.Enqueue(idBatch);
            totalCount += idBatch.Count;
            idBatch = new List<long>(batchSize);
        }
    }
```

Firstly i was facing **Command getMore failed: Cursor not found, cursor id:xxx** error so for that i have added flag `QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout`.
But now i am facing **Command getMore failed: End of file** in `foreach` loop of `mongoCursor`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248108/mongodb-error-getmore-command-failed-cursor-not-found

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i have already wen through this document and its not for resolving end of file issue.

Answer (score 0):

use async cursor /FindAsync and it will work

```
var client = new MongoClient();

  IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("school");

  var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("students");

  using (IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = await collection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()))
  {
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
      IEnumerable<BsonDocument> batch = cursor.Current;
      foreach (BsonDocument document in batch)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(document);
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
    }
  }
```

Just test like it what it gives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used above async code but still its throwing following error:   [Inner Exception]
Message:
 Command getMore failed: End of file.
Stack Trace:
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()

Comment: Just test without writing your "some query". I think its query syntax issue or query and condition is wrong or time consuming. debug the inner query and try to refine it .mongoCollection.Find(Query.And(some query))