# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: cursor id 9202872427362649383 not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My friend and I are working on a project and we built a bot to query the Twitter API at intervals, but afyer a while, we get this error

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: cursor id 9202872427362649383 not found"

What could be the cause and how can it be fixed?

The database is hosted on Atlas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Error: getMore command failed: Cursor not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248108/mongodb-error-getmore-command-failed-cursor-not-found) - While the question itself doesn't contain exactly the same error, the underlying reason is most probably due to a cursor timeout, as outlined in the answers.